# Is it possible to use built-in angular functions in the view?

Tags: angularjs

I could have sworn that writing code like this in the view would work:

```
<div ng-if="angular.isDefined(2)">
    It works
</div>
```

but it does not seem to be working. Do we really have to write a function in the controller for this sort of thing, or am I missing something?

I have a function that I would really like to use in the view:

```
angular.isBlank = function(qualificaiton) = {
    if(qualification == null || qualification === undefined){
        return false;
    }
    else 
       return true;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this, or am I out of luck?

Comment: you mean $scope.isBlank = ... ?

Comment: why not use Angular Services concept or a Global Function with $rootScope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polluting the scope isn't the best idea, you may get problems with not encapsulating functionality properly down the road amongst other things.

A better way would be to use a filter.

```
<div ng-if="{(2 | myFilter)}">
    It works!!!
</div>
```

A plunker demonstrating what I am talking about...

https://plnkr.co/edit/kL86WqrHpgY4asxcVlCg?p=preview

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

(never tested) you can keep a reference of angular in the controller scope like that:

```
$scope.myAngular = angular;
```

Then in your view :

```
<div ng-if="myAngular.isDefined(2)">
    It works
</div>
```

**EDIT** Am not sure about the bad side of this, so use it at your own risk.